# How to remove the double quotes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, chai

I am trying to pass in

```
"HO_1,HO_2"
```

from a cucumber feature file.

I am trying to pass that value into a Chai include call, so it needs to be in the format of:

```
"HO_1", "HO_2"
```

I am currently using a split and join to create the format as such:

```
const splitE = (('"'+(eventTag.split(",")).join('", "')+'"'));
```

And this `console.log`s:

```
"HO_1", "HO_2"
```

But when I then try to pass splitE into the chai call:

```
expect(estring).to.include(splitE);
```

Its trying to pass the variable in as a string and it is being passed in as

```
expect(estring).to.include(""HO_1", "HO_2"");
```

And it doesn't work, how do I remove the quotes around what I have passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are trying to do is not yet supported in `Chai` framework, because **[`.include()` method](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_include)** accepts only one `value`, so both your `values` will be treated as one `string`.

What you can do is to use [**`.satisfy()` method**](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy), to check for both `substrings` :

```
expect(estring).to.satisfy(estring =>
  eventTag.split(",").some(b => estring.includes(b))
);
```

You can check, the **[Check that string contains multiple other strings](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/858)** open issue, in Github for further details.

Comment: Chai requires the input to be the quoted and comma separated list, "a","b" so i need to keep the quotes, just not the double quotes being passed to the function

Comment: @Karl In that case you need to change your code to match both `substrings`, you can use `.satisfy()` for example, I updated my answer, with a drawback for this case.

Answer (score 0):

What about just `slice` all, but quotes?

```
expect(estring).to.include(splitE.slice(1, -1));
```